# Roadmap for EOL of deprecated API functions

Tags: php, podio

I support some platforms that use an old version of [Podio-PHP-SDK (v3)](https://github.com/podio/podio-php/tree/podio-php3). Also, there are some deprecated functions still in use, such as PodioItem::get_basic.

Does an official or unoffical roadmap for the EOL of API-functions exist? Your support told me to look in your product forum for EOL of functions, but there is no information, and as an example, PodioItem::get_basic is marked as deprecated for months.

Comment: What is PHP-SDK (v3)?

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: Please note that this is not the official support forum for any product. If they encouraged you to use it as such, please point them to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support If you feel your question is on topic here as described in the [help] please word it to address the Stack Overflow community, not an individual organisation, as they might not be the ones answering.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. From their readme: This is the third revision of the Podio PHP Client and it is very different than previous versions. If you are familiar with older versions almost everything have changed. If you need the older version it is available as a download at https://github.com/podio/podio-php/zipball/v2. It will not be updated and bugs will not be fixed.

Comment: Thank you, but meanwhile I've seen, that deprecated functions are implemented also in newer SDK versions. To refactor the code, I must know, which deprecated functions of server-side API will be removed soon. Support of podio has referred me to Stackoverflow, to communicate directly with the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API documentation [1] is the definitive source for supported requests. The client libraries are not currently being maintained by the Podio team.

[1] https://developers.podio.com/doc